# Window handling in java selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Successfully handled the child window in java selenium but the cursor is not moving forward to the password field. My code is below

```
package perfect;

//import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
//import java.util.Iterator;
//import java.util.Set;


public class java {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/gt0849/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64(1)/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    //driver.quit();
    System.out.print("Welcome to Make my trip");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().forward();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"SW\"]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div")).click();
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String childWindowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if(!childWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindow)){
            driver.switchTo().window(childWindowHandle);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("abv.com");
            //driver.wait(2000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.id("yDmH0d")).sendKeys("11");
            driver.navigate().forward();
            
            
            
            
        }

}
}
}
```

Comment: What actually fails? I presume that your `click()` on the element that is a child of the element with `id=SW` is meant to open the child window, but how do you ensure that the window the driver switches to is the correct one? A list of windows would include the main window and the child window, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wait for the second window to come up before getting the window handles. To make sure, print the window handles and check

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate your answer?

Comment: I guess more generally the question would be... what do you do if the other handle isn't there yet? Is it possible to halt execution until the window arrives? (not a selenium guy, so I don't really know.)

Answer (score 0):

In the automation testing services we try to add wait after the window switching to ensure the current active window is now ready to handle the action.We can also use getWindowHandle( ) for better handling of windows

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code did the trick for me,

```
try {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    System.out.print("Welcome to Make my trip");
    driver.navigate().forward();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"SW\"]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div")).click();
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String childWindowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
if (!childWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(parentWindow)) {
    driver.switchTo().window(childWindowHandle);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"))
    .sendKeys("abv.com");
    driver.navigate().forward();
    driver.findElement(By.id("yDmH0d")).sendKeys("11");
    driver.navigate().forward();
}
    }
    
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All I did is add a 2 second wait before entering the username.